# running code in localhost with the app name as route

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am able to run the application of my index.js with `node index.js`,

// index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

so if i hit localhost:3000 i will be getting the response in the browser as **Hello World**.

Is it possible that i can access the application in localhost:3000/app  and get the same response?

what am i trying is to have the application base url as localhost:3000/app

what should be the change in the code ??

I don't whether i am asking its correct or not ?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely have to use an express `Router` object. You will then have to put all your routes under a router master called `appBase` in this example :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

var appBase = express.Router();

app.use('/app', appBase);

appBase.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.baseUrl); // /app
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Everything is well explained on the official express documentation : http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl

Comment: your `appBase.get` will be called on a GET http request made for `localhost:3000/app/hello` right ?

Comment: The response will be sent over `localhost:3000/app` GET call and he's asking for having the application base url as localhost:3000/app not for single request but as a `baseUrl`

Comment: my bad i misunderstood the question ! I upvoted your answer. Best

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const handler = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
};

app.get('/', handler)
app.get('/app', handler)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```